# Oracle - Missing Right Parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle, select

The table structure is as follows:

**NOTE**: The names used are for illustrative purposes only.

Table T1 - col1 INT, col2 CHAR, col3 VARCHAR

Table T2 - col1 INT, col2 VARCHAR col3 CHAR

Table T3 - col1 INT - col1 from Table 2 col2 INT - col2 from Table T col3 INT

```
SELECT tt1.col2, COUNT(tt1.col1) FROM T1 tt1, T2 tt2, T3 tt3 WHERE tt2.col1 = tt3.col1 AND      
tt3.col2 = tt1.col1 GROUP BY tt1.col1, tt1.col2 HAVING EVERY (tt2.col3 = 'something');
```

This shows an error that matches the title of the question; However, no error is reported if I remove the **HAVING** clause.

Is the query syntactically correct?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You can move your `having` clause into the `where`. The specific problem is that you've added the word "EVERY", which is not Oracle syntax.

Comment: @Ben: What if I need every to check if every tuple has 'something' in col3, in table tt2?

Comment: Then it can still go in the `where` clause. You're using implicit inner joins so you're not going to turn an outer join into an inner join mistakenly.

Comment: where tt2.col3 is not null then null.  Absence of null means it has something.

Comment: @xQbert: I do not meant to talk about null. Something is any valid string.

Comment: @Ben: i.e. WHERE .... AND ALL(tt2.col3 = 'string')... ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT tt1.col2, COUNT(tt1.col1) 
FROM T1 tt1 
JOIN T3 tt3 ON (tt3.col2 = tt1.col1)
JOIN T2 tt2 ON (tt2.col1 = tt3.col1)
WHERE tt2.col3 = 'something'
GROUP BY tt1.col2;
```

It doesn't appear that you need a HAVING clause.  You use a HAVING clause when you need to filter results after your GROUP BY has been executed.  For example, if you wanted only the records with a count(tt1.col1) greater than 10, you would use a HAVING clause.   (HAVING count(tt1.col1) > 10)

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Not that it is necessary for this statement to work, as you could write something more similar to your original query, but I always prefer explicit join syntax.  In my opinion it is much more readable and obvious as to how the tables are being joined when the logic to do so is in the ON clause and not in the WHERE clause where you would have other filtering operations.